# Can't upgrade due to not enough space in /boot

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, hard-drive

/boot$ ls

abi-3.8.0-19-generic         initrd.img-3.8.0-29-generic
abi-3.8.0-25-generic         lost+found
abi-3.8.0-26-generic         memtest86+.bin
abi-3.8.0-27-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.8.0-29-generic         System.map-3.8.0-19-generic
abi-3.8.0-30-generic         System.map-3.8.0-25-generic
abi-3.8.0-31-generic         System.map-3.8.0-26-generic
config-3.8.0-19-generic      System.map-3.8.0-27-generic
config-3.8.0-25-generic      System.map-3.8.0-29-generic
config-3.8.0-26-generic      System.map-3.8.0-30-generic
config-3.8.0-27-generic      System.map-3.8.0-31-generic
config-3.8.0-29-generic      vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
config-3.8.0-30-generic      vmlinuz-3.8.0-25-generic
config-3.8.0-31-generic      vmlinuz-3.8.0-26-generic
grub                         vmlinuz-3.8.0-27-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic  vmlinuz-3.8.0-29-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-25-generic  vmlinuz-3.8.0-30-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-26-generic  vmlinuz-3.8.0-31-generic
initrd.img-3.8.0-27-generic

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to install **Ubuntu Tweak** to remove old kernels if you are unhappy or unwilling to remove them via the **Terminal**.

1 - [Ubuntu Tweak Download](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak/0.8.x/0.8.6/+download/ubuntu-tweak_0.8.6-1_all.deb)

Once you have installed **Ubuntu Tweak**, open the application up.

2 - Click on **Start Janitor**

[image]

Select **Old Kernel** & then click **Clean**

[image]

Enter your password when asked, press enter and now only the old Linux Kernels will be removed.